# qBitTorrent snap not working

Tags: snap, qbittorrent

I tried using qBitTorrent after doing a clean install of 20.04.  When I ran a test search, it returned an error.  I tried turning all permissions on and that made no difference.  Since I still have a 19.10 install on another computer I confirmed qBitTorren works there using the regular install.  I then tried the snap install.  Same network issue as on 20.04. 
I added the qBitTorrent repository to apt and downloaded direct.  That version works fine.  (It also starts much more quickly and seems snappier.  Pun intended, of course!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with the default permissions that the snap builder included.  If you look at the qbittorrent log you can see it is having connection problems.

```
snap list
```

to find the name of the qbittorrent snap.  In my case qbittorrent-arnatious

```
snap connect qbittorrent-arnatious:network-manager :network-manager
snap connect qbittorrent-artanious:network-control :network-control
```

Answer (score 2):

As a work-around, instead of using the snap, direct install it from the developer.  You can find information on that here: https://www.qbittorrent.org/download.php

Or, if you're a wee bit smarter, follow this suggestion:
    What was wrong with installing it from the repository by sudo apt-get install qbittorrent? – N0rbert Apr 30 at 8:07

Comment: What was wrong with installing it from [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/qbittorrent) by `sudo apt-get install qbittorrent`?

Comment: Probably nothing.  TBH, it didn't occur to me. LOL

Comment: In the repository, it's quite an old version, the current one is 4.3.3, apart from it nothing.